# Not able to establish a oracle connection through jar when running in unix server

Tags: java

We have a job (jar)we can able to run in local(eclips) and other environment(unix) but same code we are not able to run in one of the unix server. when i cal a jar file from putty(java -jar filename.jar) session started but nothing happening(no error or success) it is just staying idle.i have put few sops and found that it is staying idle when it is caling DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pwd)..it is not comming out of that.
few observations:
1.No java version issue-checked
2.DB port enabled properly
3.No Exceptions /error throwing

Comment: Check ojdbc.jar is packed inside of your runnable jar

Comment: Hi manoj, yes it is there and i guess no problem with ojdbc jar

Answer (score 0):

If the call to `connect` is taking a looong time, then the most likely explanations are:

- The connection is being blocked *somewhere* on the client, on the server, or somewhere in between.
- You have the connection details incorrect and you are somehow connecting to the wrong place; e.g. to an IP that doesn't route correctly to the server.

There are lots of possible mistakes you could have made, and it is difficult to enumerate all of them.  Especially, since you have given no details of the network environment or your connection parameters.

Comment: Hello Stephen,I think your first point would be having more chances . Reg your second point, ihave the explanation. I have tested the same job in Dev and prod Environment(Running the same jar in unix using putty ) and also tested the same in my local also in eclipse .

Comment: On your first point can i have some clue how to check the connection block on server end ?